# Search Files with windows explorer

Tags: ms-access

i have a list of many organizations, each org. has lists of hundreds of people, each person has a scan'd document in that organizations folder, now i have a btn on my app that opens the org folder, and the user is searching for that person, but the user wants the btn to open windows explorer automatically searching a person.

i found this code:

```
Shell("c:\Windows\explorer.exe ""search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results&crumb=System.Generic.String%3A" & <variable> & "&crumb=location:<your search location>%", vbNormalFocus)
```

but windows raises the folowing error:

```
Windows Cant find ". Check if spaled correctly...
```

any suggestions ?

I'm Adding here my code:

```
Private Sub cmdView_Click()
   Dim strPath As String
   strPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Scans\" & DLookup("OrgName", "tblOrganizations", "ID=" & Me.OrgID)
   'Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & strPath & "", vbNormalFocus
   Call Shell("c:\Windows\explorer.exe ""search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results&crumb=System.Generic.String%3A" & Me.Phone & "&crumb=location:" & strPath & "%""", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you are missing another double quote somewhere... Most probably at the end of your command. And don't forget to escape it as well.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to figure it out

Comment: yes, you have an opening escaped (doubled) quote after ```explorer.exe``` and no closing one at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution, using only a common **batch (.bat) file**, which anyone can make using only notepad.exe:

```
::  Text to search for
SET name=Winamp

::  Directory to search in
SET dir=C:\Program Files (x86)

::  ** Command Line **
C:\Windows\Explorer.exe "search-ms:displayname=Search Results in %dir%&crumb=System.Generic.String:%name%&crumb=location:%dir%"
```

*Notes* -

1. The text to search for can be the full name, or just part of the name, of the file or directory to be searched for.
2. The search is NOT case sensitive, but will match a mixture of uppercase and lowercase.
3. The function will search the specified directory and all subdirectories of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Shell("c:\Windows\explorer.exe ""search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results&crumb=System.Generic.String%3A" & <variable> & "&crumb=location:<your search location>%""", vbNormalFocus)
```

This should fix it, as parakmiakos said, you missed a double (triple due to being a string) quote.

Comment: I tried it but still raising error, see my code i added in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
string folder = Uri.EscapeDataString(@"C:\");
            string file = "size:huge";
            string uri = "search:query=" + file + "&crumb=location:" + folder;
            var files = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(uri));
```

Comment: this is C# and .NET. He's asking for MS Access.